# Download offline installer xamarin 4.0.6.299

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I tried to download offline installer for Xamarin, but I can not find the version that I need.

Where can I download offline installer?

Xamarin version 4.0.6.299, Xamarin.Android 7.4.0.21,
Xamarin IOS 10.12.0.20

Comment: Why are you looking for offline installer? use/update Visual Studio and you are good to go.

Comment: Becausai iam using specific version for xamarin proyect. Couple years ago i develop a proyect and i reinstalled my terminal and i had to developed the proyect again. Could you help to find the installer?

Comment: Did you use Xamarin.Form or Xamarin.Android/iOS? if you use Xamarin.Android/iOS, you should update your project/SDK/Nuget packages to latest version, some feature added and some bug fixed in each version, also you have to support Android 8 if you want to share your app in play store. using latest version of Visual Studio is only work that you need to do. also updating old projects is not a big deal.

Comment: Or where can i download lateste offline installer for Xamarin IOS and Android. Could you help me?

Comment: Xamarin is free to use and included in all editions of Visual Studio. You could refer to this document: [Installing Xamarin in Visual Studio on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows)